# Как работает это регулярное выражение?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

В этой регулярке, которая соответствует строкам без слова foo внутри

```
^((?!foo).)*$
```

Что означает `(?!foo)` ? Как может быть позитивный просмотр вперёд без всяких символов до скобок?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это называется "отрицательное заглядывание"

В оригинале звучит так

> Starting at the current position in the expression, ensures that the given pattern will not match. Does not consume characters.

То есть, проверяет, что от текущей позиции нет нужных символов.

```
fo111 - подходит.
foo111 - уже не подходит.
afoo11 - также не подходит.
```

читать эту регулярку нужно так "для любого символа в строке не должно быть перед ним **foo**".

Comment: Не понимаю. (?!expression) - заглядывание вперёд. (?<!expression) - заглядывание назад. В регулярке используется заглядывание вперед, но при этом она работает как заглядывание назад, то смотрит, чтобы до любого символа не было foo.

Comment: @hotshot, а вы разверните исходное выражение. У вас же не `^(?!foo).$`, а `^((?!foo).)*$`, которое может быть развернуто, например, в `^((?!foo).)((?!foo).)((?!foo).)((?!foo).)$`.

В итоге и получается - после каждого сработанного символа должно выполняться условие: дальше в строке нет `foo`

Comment: @ВОРОН, спасибо, очень доходчиво.